# Android Studio WebView error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Uri

Tags: java, android, webview

The following is the code I tried to get "id" value from the currently loaded URL in webview

```
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(webView.getUrl());
        String server = uri.getAuthority();
        String path = uri.getPath();
        String protocol = uri.getScheme();
        Set<String> args = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
        String chapter = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
```

Which gives no error, but the app crashes on loading!

Original code was

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.chalklit.in/post.html?chapter=V-Maths-Addition%20&%20Subtraction&post=394");
```

Comment: What crash? Is it a NullPointerException or what?

Comment: @Joe, I am not sure how to check it. But if I provide a fixed URL it seems to be working fine. but even if the value id is empty, the app loads.